# How can I handle the access-token in devise_token_auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, token, httparty, rails-api

I am trying to create an API for an application (both in Rails), but I have many doubts regarding authentication through an API.

Contextualizing a bit what I'm doing.

- To create the API in Rails I'm using the [rails-api](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api) and
  [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) gems.
- For the application that will consume the API's services I'm using
  the [httparty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) gem.

Now the question I have is with respect to login, the description in [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#usage-tldr) about the `sign_in` path is:

```
Email authentication. Requires email and password as params. This route will return a JSON representation of the User model on successful login along with the access-token and client in the header of the response.
```

The problem is that **I don't know how to handle the `access-token`**, for example, if I execute this:

```
@result = HTTParty.post('url_of_my_api_on_heroku/auth/sign_in', :body => {"email": "someemail@example.com", "password": "ABCDEFGHI"}.to_json, :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' })
```

On the application that will consume the API's services and I display the value of `@result` I can see the user data successfully... **BUT I don't know how to get the `access-token`, nor use it**.

I need some help, please.

Comment: Looking for rails authentication right now too :D - Let me know when you find a solution.

Comment: @penne12  -  Please check out this - http://autobot.r15.railsrumble.com. This is an automated generator which will give you the code for API login. I guess that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get the access-token:

```
@result = HTTParty.post('url_of_my_api_on_heroku/auth/sign_in', :body => {"email": "someemail@example.com", "password": "ABCDEFGHI"}.to_json, :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' })

@access_token = @result_login.headers["access-token"]
```

Now `@access_token` will have the current value of the `access-token`.